Current API doc for Yubikey OTP
I have a working program to validate a Yubikey OTP based on the specification at https://developers.yubico.com/yubikey-val/Validation_Protocol_V2.0.html
But https://developers.yubico.com/yubikey-val/ indicates that project is End of Life.
Where can I find current API documentation to validate a OTP?
I think that Yubicloud (https://www.yubico.com/products/yubicloud/) is supposed to supersede the previous project. It seems that https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-java-client/ might be a current java library. I guess I could reverse engineer that, but would really like to have the raw API doc.

After much back-and-forth with Yubico support, it appears that the current documentation is: https://developers.yubico.com/OTP/Specifications/OTP_validation_protocol.html
